# Modify DataType attribute dynamically in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, modelmetadata

I have a ViewModel containing this property:

```
[Display(Name = "Email")]        
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]        
[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "Unavailable")]        
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Is there a way to set the `DataType` attribute dynamically to show it as a `DataType.Text` if it's showing "Unavailable" (the `NullDisplayText`), otherwise show it as a clickable `DataType.EmailAddress`?

Now, when the property value is null, it shows like [Unavailable](http://#) while I want to show it as Unavailable.

Comment: You can customize the display/editor template for email.

Comment: @reza-aghaei could you provide me more details how to do this?

Comment: Yes I'll post an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the display template of `EmailAddress`. To do so:

1. Create a `DisplayTemplates` folder under `Views/Shared`
2. Create an `EmailAddress.cshtml` file in `DisplayTemplates` folder
3. Add the following content to the file and save it:

   ```
   @model string
   @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model))
   {
       @ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue
   }
   else
   {
       <a href="mailto:@Model">@ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue</a>
   }
   ```

Since now, when you use a `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]` attribute for a property, your `EmailAddress` display template will be used.

You can put any logic inside it to do a custom render.

**Note:** If you want to limit the template to your specific views, let's say just for `MyModel` views, then create the `EmailAddress` template in `Views\MyModel\DisplayTemplates`.

Comment: DisplayTemplates and EditorTemplates are one of the most useful extension points in the framework for Views. Let me know if you have any problem in applying the solution :)